Azure Web App - How to get connection string into Spring web from Connection strings
I have a App service spring web app (Not Azure spring Apps).
I created a connection  string  - SQLConnectionSTRING
This stackoverflow link gives some info but not an answer stackoverflow question
Code:
@Value("${connection:absent}")
private String connection ;

Result : absent
How can I read the connection string in my app ?
(Note: Attempt 1: System.getenv("SQLConnectionSTRING") also did not work
Attempt 2 : > addding this to application props connection=${SQLConnectionSTRING} won't build at all, so does not work
Attempt3 :     @Autowired
private Environment environment;   environment.getProperty("SQLConnectionSTRING"); also not working)

I found the azures assumption in this blog blog
Now get with prefix SQLAZURECONNSTR_ works
String value = environment.getProperty("SQLAZURECONNSTR_SQLConnectionSTRING");
Type for connection string was SQLAzure
